# Should the notation for "variable is in" be different than that for "value is in"?

Tags: notation

Using the topic of Markov Decision Processes  (MDPs) as an example, but my question is meant to be more general. So let's say I have a possible set of states $S$ and at some time-step $t$ in my MDP I am in state $S_t$. I might want to be very clear and explicit if I'm communicating this to someone, so I'd write this:

$$
S_t \in S
$$

to signify that $S_t$ is an element of $S$. Then let's say I have some function $\pi : S \Rightarrow [0, 1]$ and I write some expression like:

$$
\pi(s) = RHS
$$

How do I then express that $s$ is a variable for which I can substitute any element of $S$? To be clear on why I'm having a problem with this, here is the distinction I see:

- $S_t \in S$ means that $S_t$ is an **element** of the **set** $S$. I'm happy with this.
- But $s$ is not an element of the set $S$. It's a variable which may be substituted by any element of the set $S$.

Is my (english) language correct here? Then what's the mathematical way to write it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be looking for the notation

$\forall s \in S: \pi(s) = RHS$ is read "For all $s$ in $S$, ..." and allows you to say something is true regardless of which value in $S$ we substitute $s$ by in the formula.

However, in mathematical notation, variables almost universally represent the value they're being substituted by; it is in fact tricky to refer to the variables themselves.

Comment: Ahh of course. Yep I know that one. Just don't work with this enough to have joined the dots. Thank you